# How to kill background Processes in Android having os lollipop or above?

Tags: android

Before making this thread as a duplicate :
I have asked 2 things for to display background processes and then to kill them all or manually .
I already manage to do this work correctly in android API Lvl 19.
Above API Lvl 19 it won't.

**Note:I have done google and read almost all post in StackOverflow but I did not get the appropriate answer.**

Comment: now its not possible to get onDestroy event above lollipop device on background process

Comment: what you meant by onDestroy event.
my question is about making a TaskManager which show background processes and kill them manually or killing all at once.
(This is not for commercial purpose. It is my uni project).